# Как в кластере аккордиона показывать разные иконки метки?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

У меня используются **стандартные разноцветные иконк**и в зависимости от статуса метки. Кластеризатор **pieChart** легко их объединяет и отображает разноцветный чарт, для баллуна кластера стоит **balloonAccordion**. Если мы откроем кластер состоящий из разноцветных меток, то  в балуне будут иконки **только синие**, которые по умолчанию. Как заставить балун кластера аккордиона брать тот цвет метки, какой у меня задан?

[image: цветные кластеры]

[image: стандартные иконки в аккордионе]

Балун кластера:

```
var objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    clusterBalloonContentLayout: 'cluster#balloonAccordion',
});
```

Иконки чарта кластеров:

```
objectManager.clusters.options.set({
     clusterIconLayout: 'default#pieChart',
});
```

Метки, упрощённый код:

```
 var placemark = {
   type: 'Feature',
   id: item.id,
   geometry: {
     type: 'Point',
     coordinates: item.coordinates,
   },
   options: {
     preset: 'islands#redIcon', //на самом деле тут простановка в зависимости от статуса
   ...
}}
placemarks.features.push(placemark);
objectManager.add(placemarks);
```

Comment: Приведите пример кода, с которым у вас возникли вопросы.

Comment: добавил упрощённый код и скрины, чтобы понятнее было, но тут всё стандартно. Никаких кастомов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать общий пресет иконок и задавать параметр iconColor

```
options: {
   preset: 'islands#icon',
   iconColor: icons[item.properties.state].color,
},
```